# Trying to install Java JDK from their SE Downloads page. Don't know how to use tar.gz

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk

So I am trying to install Java JDK in a more difficult manner I know. But I want to understand what I am doing. I have the tar.gz file downloaded from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). Now I used

```
tar -xzf jdk-8u71-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

on the archive to unpack it and I cd into the new folder. There is no configure file so the make method doesn't seem to work. There is a bin folder. Should I just be moving the entire directory into my usr/bin?

I am so bad at this :(. Thanks ahead of time for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the tar.gz file as a root :

```
 cd /usr/local
 tar xzf <the tar.gz file>
```

and update PATH and JAVA_HOME variable (be aware of your JDK version):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_13 
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

[more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788345/how-to-install-jdk-on-ubuntu-linux)